# Filtering a pandas data frame with a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck on something simple but I can't see it despite reading the docs and relevant SO questions. This involves filtering records from data that comes out of a WordPress database.

Create some data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'number': [1,2,3],\
        'field': ['billing_last_name', 'shipping_last_name', 'field_1435'],\
        'name': ['jones', 'smith', 'jones']}
dframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
print dframe

                field   name  number
0   billing_last_name  jones       1
1  shipping_last_name  smith       2
2          field_1435  jones       3
```

Select a subset of the data:

```
field_filter = 'billing_last_name'
number_filter = 1
choice = dframe[(dframe['field'] == field_filter) & (dframe['number'] == number_filter)]
print choice

               field   name  number
0  billing_last_name  jones       1
0    jones
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Use this result to set a variable for further filtering:

```
match = str(choice['name'])
```

Here's where the problem starts. If I filter with the variable it returns nothing:

```
print dframe[dframe['name'] == match]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [field, name, number]
Index: []
```

If I run the same filter with the string the variable holds it returns the correct result:

```
print dframe[dframe['name'] == 'jones']

               field   name  number
0  billing_last_name  jones       1
2         field_1435  jones       3
```

Yet both the variable and its contents are strings, apparently:

```
print type('jones')
print type(match)

<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

Why doesn't the filter with the variable work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`match` is actually a `pandas` `series`, not the `string` variable "jones".  In this case, you need to access the `string` values within the `series`:

```
field_filter = 'billing_last_name'
number_filter = 1
choice = dframe[(dframe['field'] == field_filter) & (dframe['number'] == number_filter)]

matches = choice['name'].values
dframe[dframe['name'].isin(matches)]
```

This assumes you can have multiple elements in `matches`.  This may / may not be the desired effect (I can update the answer).

Comment: Thank you, and also to the two other answers, which were also helpful.If my original

Comment: If my original match filter was a Series, why does type(match) show it to be a string? This is what prompted my question.

Comment: You can still convert a `series` to `string` but it will also include the additional `dtype` information.  `match = str(choice['name'])` results in: `'0    jones\nName: name, dtype: object'`  but `match = str(choice['name'].values[0]` results in `'jones'` (as desired).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `str(choice.name)` will not do what you think. The type is

```
In [205]: type(choice.name)
Out[205]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

so `str` just finds the string representation of the Series.

In order to access it the way you want, you can use the following:

```
In [206]: dframe[dframe['name'] == choice.name.values[0]]
Out[206]: 
               field   name  number
0  billing_last_name  jones       1
2         field_1435  jones       3
```

Comment: heh, beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create match as:

```
match = str(choice['name'][0])
```

cause **choice['name']** is Series